# pyzmq: Is there a shortcut for a "sendto"-like function for a ROUTER socket?

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a `ROUTER` socket, which accepts requests, does some work and sends back a response:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
socket.bind("tcp://*:1234")
sender, _, content = socket.recv_multipart()
reply = do_some_work(content)                    # Do something with the message
socket.send_multipart((sender, "", reply))
```

When sending the response, that empty string in the middle feels pretty stupid, although I know it is needed by ZeroMQ to separate the identity from the content.

I would expect a high-level language binding, such as `pyzmq`, to have a function that wraps that and provides a cleaner, less error-prone API.

I can imagine something like:

```
socket.sendto(identity, content)
```

And it will add the empty frame for me.

So - **is there anything like that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Well, AFAIK, **no, there is not.**

---

Reason **1**)
IMHO, the identity / security / ... concepts seem to me to be a sort of ex-post add-ons, easily re-using the concept of a multi-frame composition for these add-ons onto an already mature API + countless amount of such API language-bindings, some of which might, some of which might not have any similar levels of syntax freedom, such as to similarly beautify the way to call the original ZeroMQ core exposed API services. One ought somehow respect the long successful running evolution of the ZeroMQ, their indoctrinated organisation side of generating consensus over and obeying in implementation the RFC-specifications and manage the end-to-end development process, which yet spans from API v 2.1 over many years and having survived many design and technology inducted shifts up to recent days, having recently core API v 4.2.2 stable in production.

Reason **2**)
OOD/OOP Evangelists would make you soon revise your view to expect others to do this for you, once your imaginated high-level view on a request for having a
**`socket.sendto( identity, content )`** custom-specific method argumentation is based on your own view of comfort ( ref. above ) - as it is the very obvious case for using an appropriate tool -- a **subclassing** -- and there adding your own, specialised method, that extends the generic superclass behaviour and adds your wished to have comfort, all that under your control.

---

<sub>Anyway, enjoy the powers of ZeroMQ, as it can help you in many aspects of designing advanced scalable distributed heterogeneous non-blocking signalling / messaging systems. G/L on that wild and innovative ride!</sub>

Comment: I'm not convinced, but the answer is right - there is none... :(